Use up-to-date state variable in `useEffect`
Javascript binds variables to functions as they are created, which can cause 'dangling' out-of-date values to be used in useEffect.
function Counter() {
  var [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    var timeout = setInterval(() => setCount(count => count+1), 1000); // every 1'

    setTimeout(() => console.log(`Count after 10': ${count}`), 10000); // after 10'

    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, []);


  return <span>{count}</span>
}

The anonymous function of setInterval binds to count when it's 1, and therefore the console.log output isn't 10 (but 1).
Is there an elegant fix? For example, adding count as a dependency of useEffect would re-create the timeout in this case, causing unwanted behavior - although it would be a fix in many similar use cases.
Can I pass count by reference somehow without the boilerplate of wrapping it in an object and needing to keep that object in sync?

You can use a useRef hook to grab the current value of count when your timer runs out.
function Counter() {
  var [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  var countRef = useRef(count);
  useEffect(() => { 
    countRef.current = count; 
  }, [count])  
  
  useEffect(() => {
    var timeout = setInterval(() => setCount(count => count+1), 1000); // every 1'

    setTimeout(() => console.log(`Count after 10': ${countRef.current}`), 10000); // after 10'

    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, []);


  return <span>{count}</span>
}


Known as useLatest in many hook libraries, or "ref boxing" in general.
